# Load a part of the page without AJAX

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, css

I'm developing a web site where I want the left menu to stay fix, while the content of the clicked option is loaded.

Actually, what I do is that each menu link using AJAX it return the requested content. Everything works fine but I would like to avoid it because then statistics are difficult to follow (among some other things like Google boots).

How can I do the same affect/similar (http://www.foundcrelamps.com/) without javascript?

Comment: Like [this](http://www.rocknrun.in/#/index)?

Comment: How about heavily caching the page, and, depending on the hashtag, do ajax? Ah wait, indexing problem will happen then. This I think is very reason people don't hashtags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is a bit different. I'd make the links on the menu valid links that point to the content. Eg `Contacte` to point to `http://www.foundcrelamps.com/contacte` so that if you paste that link in the browser, it will load the page directly.

Then keep the ajax, so that the user does not reload the whole page on every click.

You can use [History.js](https://github.com/balupton/History.js/) to keep the browser history and modify the URL so that back/next buttons work, even with ajax.

Edit, if you use conventional `a` elements with standard `href` it might look like this:

```
$('a').click(function(){
    $('YOUR CONTAINER').load($(this).attr('href'));
    return false; // so that it does not load the whole page
});
```

Then on the server you should do something like this:

```
/* AJAX check  */
$isAjax = false;
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']==='XMLHttpRequest') {
    $isAjax = true;
}

if (!$isAjax) {
    outputHeader();
}

outputMainContent();

if (!$isAjax) {
    outputFooter();
}
```

This way when you do ajax, you will load only the inner content. When not, it will load the whole page.

There is an alternative method - you might load the whole page with jQuery but only use inner part of the html to replace the original content.

Comment: If I do this, then a click on the menu will load all the page, which I don't want.

Comment: Ok. I see the trick, but then, why should <a> points to http://www.foundcrelamps.com/contacte. I'm sure there is a reason but I can't see why.

Comment: So that google scrapes the page correctly. And if someone does a copy/paste on the link, the next user will be able to reach the page.